# PHP gethostbyname security implications

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP application.
There is a requirement to find IP's by hostname and i have to resort to gethostbynamel for that.
Looks like there is no other way.

I was wondering if there are any security implications related to this.
I am validating the hostname given as input from end-user by using regular expressions.

I have two options:

```
1) When user submits a form with hostname, validate it and use gethostbynamel
(or)
2) When user submits a form with hostname, validate it store it in database and use cron job which runs gethostbynamel
```

Will there be any difference in the above methods?

Security is top priority for the application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much inputting and concurrent users you're going to have. As long you sanitize, validate and clean everything before you go in the database there shouldn't be security issues from the above methods.

The Cron Job method would be best if you have thousands of entries happening concurrently, having a separate process to getHostByName would save some seconds of loading time after the users clicks the save button as php would have less to compute.

Thanks for reading.